# Selectable - skip elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have:

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr><td>a1</td><td>a2</td><td>a3</td><td>a4</td><td>a5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>b1</td><td>b2</td><td>b3</td><td>b4</td><td>b5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>c1</td><td>c2</td><td class="no">c3</td><td>c4</td><td>c5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>d1</td><td>d2</td><td>d3</td><td>d4</td><td>d5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>e1</td><td>e2</td><td>e3</td><td>e4</td><td>e5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>f1</td><td>ff2</td><td>f3</td><td>f4</td><td>f5</td></tr>
</table>
```

and:

```
$( "#table" ).selectable({
    filter: 'td:not(.no)',
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var selected = $(this).find('.ui-selected');

        console.log(selected);
    }
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5RxB2/

How is the best way to skip elements? I would like have always a rectangle or square.

Some examples:

1) I selected a1, a2, b1, b2 - this is OK

2) I selected a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3 - this is OK

3) I selected a2, b2 - this is OK

4) I selected:

a1, a2, a3, a4

b1, b2, b3, b4

c1, c2,  a4  //a3 haveclass no

d1, d2, d3, d4

So, I would like to receive a rectangle or square. This should get always first selected (in this example a1) and reject others than (a1, a2, b1, b2) - so this should reject TD upward and sideward from c3 (class no).

Is this possible? If yes, how? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1)** Using selector in a `filter`:

```
$( "#table" ).selectable({
    filter: 'td:not(.no)',
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var selected = $(this).find('.ui-selected');

        console.log(selected.filter(':first,:last'));
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nk6x6/)

---

**Option 2)** Using selector in the `find`:

```
$( "#table" ).selectable({
    filter: 'td:not(.no)',
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var selected = $(this).find('.ui-selected:first,.ui-selected:last');

        console.log(selected);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPsk/)